# C3.js : Months name are not showing continuously

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I am using C3.js to plot below graph but months name are not showing continuously on x-axis even data is showing, please let me know how can I resolve it
for x-axis data should be like [mar-2017 , April-2017,May-2017,June-2017,July-2017...so on]

[image]

```
 var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: bindingElement,
    data: {
        x:'x',
        columns: plotData,
        order:false,
        type: 'bar',
        groups: datagroup
      },
            bar: {
        width: {
            ratio: 0.70 
        }
        },
      axis: {
        x: {
        type: 'timeseries',
          tick: {
            rotate: 30,
            format: '%b%Y'
          }
        }
      }
  });
```

Comment: Please provide some code what you tried

Comment: try x axis type as category. http://c3js.org/reference.html#axis-x-type

Comment: I already used 'timeseries' type for x-axis

Comment: @SanjeevS please have a look for code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting **[axis.x.tick.culling](http://c3js.org/reference.html#axis-x-tick-culling)** to **false**:

```
axis: {
  x: {
    tick: {
      culling: false
    }
  }
}
```

It prevents c3 from hiding particular ticks.

Answer (score 0):

try this one [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevsp89/2myjbmtv/)

```
var chart = c3.generate({
bindto: '#chart',
data: {
    columns: [
        ['data1', 30000, 20000, 10000, 40000, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        ['data2', 0, 0, 0, 0, 15000, 25000, 50000, 10000], 
        ['data3', 0, 0, 0, 0, 15000, 25000, 50000, 10000]
    ],
    order:false,
    type: 'bar',
    groups:  [
        ['data2', 'data3']
    ]
  },
        bar: {
    width: {
        ratio: 0.70 
    }
    },
  axis: {
    x: {
    type: 'category',
    categories:["mar-2017" , "April-2017","May-2017","June-2017","July-2017","August-2017","September-2017","October-2017"],
      tick: {
        rotate: 30,
        format: '%b%Y'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Or I think that your date format is incorrect for the JSON Data,
You can also try with time series as below

```
var chart = c3.generate({
bindto: '#chart',
data: {
  x: 'x',
    columns: [
    ['x', '2017-01-01' , '2017-02-01','2017-03-01','2017-04-01','2017-05-01','2017-06-01','2017-07-01','2017-08-01'],
        ['data1', 30000, 20000, 10000, 40000, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        ['data2', 0, 0, 0, 0, 15000, 25000, 50000, 10000], ['data3', 0, 0, 0, 0, 15000, 25000, 50000, 10000]
    ],
    order:false,
    type: 'bar',
    groups:  [
        ['data2', 'data3']
    ]
  },
        bar: {
    width: {
        ratio: 0.70 
    }
    },
  axis: {
    x: {
    type: 'timeseries', 
      tick: {
        rotate: 30,
        format: '%b %Y'
      }
    }
  }
 });
```

Happy coding